# Index a graph with ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, graph

I can describe my data as a graph, I have nodes and links between them (each of theme have their own data). Each node has a huge number of links connected to him.

My goal: I need to query all nodes with/without a link holding a specific data.

Ideally I would like to create a parent-child relation between the link type with both node types, but this is not possible with Elastic (multiple parents). How would you index it?

Comment: Are you sure it's a good idea to store this in Elasticsearch? Neo4j should be a better approach.

Comment: I've read about it in the last couple of hours and you are absolutely correct. Thank you.