# Directed Graph Modeling and Retrieving in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a set of data which can be visualised as directed graph:

A{id:1, parent:null},B{id:2, parent:1,3},C{id:3, parent:null},D{id:4, parent:2},F{id:5, parent:4},G{id:6, parent:3}

[image]

What is the best way to model these kind of data (child can have multiple parents) in ElasticSearch and how to retrieve the whole graph given one of the node id?

---

## Update

People suggested to use Graph DB, but I can only use ElasticSearch. So if I model the graph as edges in ElasticSearch (since I only care about the linkage information). Here is how the data looks like for the above example:

{id:e1, from:v1, to:v2}, {id:e2, from:v3, to:v2}, {id:e3, from:v3, to:v6}, {id:e4, from:v2, to:v4}, {id:e5, from:v4, to:v5}

How can I retrieve the whole graph with performance?
Also I would like to know is this a good modelling of graph in ElasticSearch?

Comment: I suggest aggregate http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AggregateOrientedDatabase.html by parent, can you find whole associations when get a parent? all children I mean? can you save all aggregated parents with children?

Comment: There is a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33410242/index-a-graph-with-elasticsearch) and someone there recommends the same approach as I would, i.e. Neo4J would be better suited for this kind of need.

Comment: Although, last week at Elastic{ON} there was an announcement about an [upcoming Graph feature](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/3624) in Kibana which will allow you to visualize your data in ES as graphs... Might be worth checking out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add another `gid` field to your documents, which could contain the graph ID

```
{gid: 123, id:e1, from:v1, to:v2}, 
{gid: 123, id:e2, from:v3, to:v2}, 
{gid: 123, id:e3, from:v3, to:v6}, 
{gid: 123, id:e4, from:v2, to:v4}, 
{gid: 123, id:e5, from:v4, to:v5}
```

That way you would be able to retrieve all nodes of your graph using just that ID in one single `term` query and then you can reconstruct the graph using the `from`/`to` fields.

In the [Node-RED](http://nodered.org/) project, for instance, they store their flow graphs as JSON documents and all nodes pertaining to the same flow share the same flow ID (see the `z` fields in the [sample flow here](http://nodered.org/docs/getting-started/second-flow.html)).

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Any idea how to handle the case if the new edges may be added later, so it may connect one graph to another graph. Are we going to update all gid of the edges in both graph to a new gid? Is this performing?

Comment: If you add a new edge between two graphs, thus making a new bigger graph, there are several possibilities, but the simplest one is to update the `gid` of all the nodes in both graphs to a new ID value. It might not be the most performing way of doing it, but again, ES might not be the best technology to model graphs either. Otherwise, you can decide (like in Node-RED) that any node being drawn on the same canvas has the same graph ID, even if there are some disjoint sub-graphs.